# Style-aware icons for folders in Nautilus / Gnome Files

Tags: icons, gnome3, nautilus, gtk, user-folders

I'm running Gnome 3 on Fedora 25, and many of the xdg-compliant standard user directories (like "Desktop", "Downloads", "Public", etc) have a special icon when viewed in Nautilus (i.e. the Files app). These icons also change to match the active GTK Icons theme, as managed by Gnome Tweak Tool.

Is there a way to make Nautilus use such a style-sensitive icon for custom folders? I ask because I want to make a Templates folder (to use the features mentioned in this [Fedora Magazine article](https://fedoramagazine.org/creating-using-nautilus-templates/)), and I'd like Nautilus to show that folder with Gnome's default set of "Template Folder" icons, located at:

```
/usr/share/icons/<theme>/<size>/places/folder-templates.png
```

I know how to set a file/folder's icon to a specific image (discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217757/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-files-icon#219560) for reference), but not how to set an icon to one that will follow the active GTK Icon theme.

Is there a way to do this? Or are the style-aware icons hard-coded in Gnome/Nautilus and can't be customized?

EDIT: Looks like Nautilus uses the correct, style-aware Templates icon after all. I set ~/Templates as my XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR via 'xdg-user-dirs-update --set', and now Nautilus is using the right icon for Templates. But my question still stands for folders that aren't xdg user directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it to late, but anyway.

To achieve what you asked you need to set an icon name `folder-templates` in `metadata::custom-icon-name` attribute. You can use `gio` to modify the folder attributes:

```
gio set /path/to-dir metadata::custom-icon-name "folder-templates"
```

Then the icon will depend from GTK Icon theme.

Comment: It's never too late :) Thanks for the answer!